# Ordering data based on a rotation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sorting

Suppose I have a dataset:

`ID    NEXT  ORDER
1456  1679  1 
1679  1679  2
1578  1679  3
9492  1679  4`

The only column in this dataset that ever changes is NEXT. ID is always unique, NEXT always correlates to a single ID and will be duplicated throughout every row. ORDER is a sequential int.

I need an orderby, or other SQL statement that will perform the following sort:

---

The NEXT ID is always at the bottom of the ordering.

The ID that has the sequentially greater ORDER after NEXT's ORDER is always at the top

The ordering is then sequential starting with the second to top row's ORDER being the next after The top row's order

---

Example:

for the above table the ordering would be 

`1578
9492
1456
1679`

---

Another table where next has changed:

`ID    NEXT  ORDER
1456  1578  1 
1679  1578  2
1578  1578  3
9492  1578  4`

would be:

`9492
1456
1679
1578`

Comment: also please tag the relevant database you are using like SQLServer,oracle,mysql,postgres..

Comment: what if the NEXT is is the Highest Order by e.g. 9492? Return the order as it is in the table?

Comment: @Matt that is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Exsting query
select ...
from ...

-- New
INNER JOIN (select top 1 [ORDER] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ID=[Next]) o ON 1=1

-- Rest of existing query
WHERE ...

--ORDER BY clause
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [order] > o.[Order] THEN -9999999+[order] else [order] end
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a2d62/4/0)
(Fiddle uses Postgresql, as Sql Server seems to be broken at the moment there).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Joel's answer only using window function instead of INNER JOIN or CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #temp t
ORDER BY
    CASE
       WHEN t.[Order] > MAX(CASE WHEN ID = [NEXT] THEN [ORDER] END) OVER () THEN -999999999 + t.[Order]
       ELSE t.[Order]
    END
```

And here is a version using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    #temp t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Order] FROM #temp WHERE ID = NEXT) n
ORDER BY
    CASE
       WHEN t.[Order] > n.[Order] THEN -99999999 + t.[Order]
       ELSE t.[Order]
    END
```

Comment: I _**love**_ APPLY, but as the result of the inner query should be consistent for every row, I think the INNER JOIN  is the better option in this case. Plus one for the windowing function, though. That's probably the best overall option. It's likely faster, and you contain the code for ordering the results entirely to the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am not sure I am following why you feel the cross apply wouldn't yield the same result as your in every instance? The CROSS APPLY in this case is basically the exactly the same as your inner join because you are joining on 1 = 1 and I am not passing any value from table into the APPLY and therefore it is fully contained within the order by just like yours.  The top one is with window function with conditional aggregation so no need for apply or innner join with that one.

Comment: Yes, it will return the same result. I have less confidence in the query optimizer's ability to recognize the statement inside the apply operator is not using any data from the outer query, though I confess that I haven't actually looked at an execution plan.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yeah I haven't looked either would be interesting to see.  I would be particularly curious about the execution plan of the window function versus the others perhaps I will get around to checking that out at somepoint

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp(ID      INT
              , [NEXT]  INT
              , [ORDER] INT);

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
      (1456
     , 1679
     , 1),
      (1679
     , 1679
     , 2),
      (1578
     , 1679
     , 3),
      (9492
     , 1679
     , 4);
```

QUERY:

```
DECLARE @rowcount INT;

SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(1)
FROM   #temp
WHERE  [ORDER] >
              (SELECT [ORDER]
               FROM   #temp
               WHERE  ID = [NEXT]);

SELECT ID
FROM
         (SELECT *
              , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ORDER])
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  [ORDER] >
                        (SELECT [ORDER]
                        FROM   #temp
                        WHERE  ID = [NEXT])
                        UNION
                        SELECT *
                            , rn = @rowcount + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ORDER])
                        FROM   #temp
                        WHERE  [ORDER] <=
                                      (SELECT [ORDER]
                                       FROM   #temp
                                       WHERE  ID = [NEXT])) AS A
ORDER BY rn;
```

RESULT:

[image]